# UIsearchbar searching for email and username

Tags: ios, swift, list, search

I have UIsearchbar in my app view. The UIsearchbar allows the user to search by username. we need to add one more feature is to allow the search by username and email address. I want to ask how I can modify my search function to search username and email?

```
public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredUsers = users.filter({( user : User) -> Bool in
        print(searchText)
        return user.username.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

    })
    tableViewUsers.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: may be return user.username.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) &&  user.email.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()). ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri - actually use `||` for the OR function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `OR` both predicates. A more efficient API than `lowercased().contains()` is `range(of:options: .caseInsensitive)`.

```
public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredUsers = users.filter { 
        $0.username.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
        $0.email.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
    tableViewUsers.reloadData()
}
```

Other options which can be combined are [`diacriticInsensitive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1412313-diacriticinsensitive) and [`anchored`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/compareoptions/1410321-anchored)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
filteredUsers = users.filter { $0.username.lowercased().contains(toSearch)
                               || $0.email.lowercased().contains(toSearch) }
```

Comment: You need to put back the line that defines `toSearch`. Someone looking at this answer might thing you meant `searchText` and then wonder why the search isn't working.